# Finding where the function is defined

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$f(x) $= $\sqrt{ax^2+9}$ 
 a is a parameter that is greater than 0,

I need to find the place the domain of this function,

so to do that I know that the numbers under the sqrt aren't negative at all times,
so

$ax^2$+9 $=$0
and I'm stuck right here, what is the next step I should do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I teach my students to solve these kinds of questions like so:

> Consider $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in (0,\infty)$.
>
> Then the following are equivalent:
>
> $\sqrt{ax^2+9}  \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> $ax^2+9  \in [0,\infty)$
>
> $ax^2  \in [-9,\infty)$
>
> $x^2  \in [\frac{-9}{a},\infty)$
>
> $\mathrm{true}$
>
> So for all $a \in (0,\infty)$, we have that for all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ the expression $\sqrt{ax^2+9}$ makes sense and denotes a real number iff $\mathrm{true}$. In other words, for all $a \in (0,\infty)$, the domain of $f(x) = \sqrt{ax^2+9}$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

I should add that I don't like this talk of "finding" the domain of a function. The domain is always given; if you're trying to find something, what you're trying to find is the *support* of the entity of interest, and the entity of interest is a **partial** function, and not really a function at all.

For example, define a partial function $$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ by the formula $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$. Then the support of $f$ is $[-1,1]$. The domain of $f$ is just $\mathbb{R}$. See what I mean? The domain is always given; you don't "find" it. What you're really finding is the support.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $ax^2+9\geq 9$, hence it is never zero. what can you conclude from that for the domain of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT, in order to find when:

$$\sqrt{\text{a}x^2+9}\space\in\mathbb{R}\tag1$$

When $\text{a}>0$

1. When $x=0$:
   $$\sqrt{\text{a}\cdot0^2+9}=\sqrt{0+9}=\sqrt{9}=3\tag2$$
2. When $x>0$:
   $$\sqrt{\text{a}x^2+9}\space>\space\sqrt{9}=3\space>\space0\tag3$$
3. When $x<0$:
   $$\sqrt{\text{a}x^2+9}\space>\space\sqrt{9}=3\space>\space0\tag4$$

> So, what can say about the domain?

Comment: Well, is it $x >= $3?

Comment: @Shadi No, because when $\text{a}\space\wedge\space x>0$ than the square root is always bigger than $3$

Answer (score 0):

> so to do that I know that the numbers under the sqrt aren't negative at all times,
>   so
>   
>   $ax^2$+9 $=$0
>   and I'm stuck right here, what is the next step I should do next?

More precisely: expressions under a square root (or under any **even** $n$th-root) cannot be negative. So whenever you see $\sqrt{g(x)}$, you need $g(x) \ge 0$. In your case, you want to solve the inequality:
$$ax^2+9 \ge 0$$
where the parameter $a$ is given to be positive. You can solve this with the standard techniques you may have seen to solve quadratic inequalities, but it is in fact very easy to see that this inequality is satisfied *for all $x$* because squares of real numbers are never negative:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \;:\; x^2 \ge 0 \implies ax^2 \ge 0 \implies ax^2+9 \ge 0$$
In other words: every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies this inequality, hence the domain is...

Answer (score 0):

Work the expression from inside to outside.

- $x^2$ can always be evaluated,
- $ax^2$ can always be evaluated,
- $ax^2+9$ can alway be evaluated,
- $\sqrt{ax^2+9}$ can be evaluated provided the argument of the square root isn't negative; as you said, this doesn't occur (sum of a product of positive numbers with a positive number).

So evaluation is possible for any $x$.

Answer (score 0):

For real solutions you want non-negative arguments to the square root:
$$
ax^2 +9 \ge 0 
$$
Now we need equivalence transformations of that inequality:
$$
a x^2 \ge -9
$$
We now need to case distinguish the possible $a$ values.

1.) If $a = 0$  we end up with
$$
0 \ge -9
$$
which is true, and $x$ does not show up, so any $x$ will be fine.

We now know $a \ne 0$, so we can divide both sides of the inequality.
The tricky bit is that for negative valued $a$, the order relation would flip from $\ge$ to $\le$.

2.) So for $a > 0$ we have
$$
x^2 \ge -9/ a
$$
which is true for any value of $x$, as $x^2$ is positive and $-9/a$ is negative.

3.) Finally for $a < 0$ we have
$$
x^2 \le -9/a 
$$
both sides are positive, so we can take the square root of both sides, as the square root is defined and it keeps the order relation intact, as the square root is strictly monotone:
$$
x \le \sqrt{-9/a}
$$